# Execute store procedure like a "table" for SELECT operator (MS SQL SERVER)

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, select

Is it possible to execute store procedure 
like a "table" for `SELECT` operator (MS SQL SERVER)?

Something like

```
SELECT TotalSum FROM exec MyStoreProcedure '2011/11/01', '2011/11/01'
```

I mean somehow integrate it into the `SELECT` operator?

Thank you!

---

Thanks guys!

The solution what I did is based on your answers:

```
declare @result table (f1 varchar(20),f2 varchar(20), CodProducto int, NomProducto varchar(1000), Costo decimal, Cantidat int, Total decimal)
INSERT INTO @result exec  MyStoreProcedure '20111201', '20111201'
select * from @result
```

Comment: Nope, but you can insert those results on a table (if you know the columns of the result dataset of your sp, of course)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I supposed your proc returns several columns and you just want one, right?

small workaround is to add the result of the proc to a table variable and then select from it

```
create proc proc1 as
select 1 as one, 2 as two

declare @result table (one int, two int)

insert into @result
exec proc1

select one from @result
```

Comment: Question: Is it possible to put it into SQLCommand object of .NET? Will do it work?

Answer (score 5):

This would be better as a function rather than a stored procedure.

```
create function dbo.TestTable
(@var1 bit)
returns table
AS
RETURN
( select *
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    where @var1 = 1
);


select * from
dbo.TestTable(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not directly (or without altering the stored procedure to be a table-valued function).

But you could do this:

```
INSERT INTO SomeTempTableWithSchemaMatchingTheSproc (...)
EXEC MyStoredProcedure 

SELECT * FROM SomeTempTableWithSchemaMatchingTheSproc
```

SQL Server 2005 onwards, you can also use a table variable.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_xxx
AS
  select * from openquery(YOURSERVERNAME, 'exec [sp_xxx] '''','''','''','''','''','''' ')
```